# Picking random items from a list twice?

Tags: python, list, random

I have lists;

```
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
player_cards = []
```

And i have a function will deal cards.

```
def deal_cards():
    player_cards.append(random.choice(cards))
    player_cards.append(random.choice(cards))
```

I'm trying to make a blackjack game. And just want to pick random cards for the player twice using for loop or some another method. So how can i make it?

Answer (score 2):

Use sample from the random module. There, you can specify the number of elements you want to pick at random from a given set. Elements are sampled without replacement.

```py
player_cards = random.sample(cards,2)
```

Comment: Thank you i appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Simple code based on Simon Hawe solution can be as below:

```
import random
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
def deal_cards():
    return random.sample(cards, 2)
player_cards = deal_cards()
print(f'Player have a cards: {player_cards} from possible list {cards}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing that exercise right now, from the requirements in the hints (unless you were following the harder paths without reading them) it says to create a separate function for the random card and to call it twice, rather than making one that does all.

```
#Hint 5: Deal the user and computer 2 cards each using deal_card() and append().
#user_cards = []
#computer_cards = []

import random

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
user_cards = []
computer_cards = []
round = []

def deal_card():
    random_card = random.choice(cards)
    return random_card

def deal_round():
    for round in range(2):
        user_cards.append(deal_card())
        computer_cards.append(deal_card())
        round=(user_cards,computer_cards)
    print(user_cards)
    print(computer_cards)
    print(round)

deal_round()
```